# dynamic class creation in java solution

Tags: java, hibernate, dynamic, orm

I know that this will not work, which sucks IMO, but I am wondering what is my best solution.  After some searching I have found out about ORM and hibernate.  After finding out about them I have found many people who say its more hassle than it is worth and promotes laziness.  Please can anyone point me in a good direction?

```
//Setup the weapon classes
logger.info("Initializing the weapon classes.");
stat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *" + 
                            " FROM " + DB_NAME + ".weapons");
rs = stat.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    Weapon rs.getString("name") = new Weapon(rs.getint("weapon_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("description"), rs.getString("filename"), rs.getint("rarity"), rs.getint("sell_price"), rs.getint("quantity_max"), rs.getint("slot"), rs.getint("level_requirement"), rs.getint("strength_requirement"), rs.getint("dexterity_requirement"), rs.getint("intelligence_requirement"), rs.getint("enchanted_increase"), rs.getint("enchanted_cost"), rs.getint("hit_min"), rs.getint("hit_max"), rs.getint("speed"), rs.getint("elemental_type"), rs.getint("elemental_hit_min"), rs.getint("elemental_hit_max"));
}
```

I know this has been asked many times, but I am just finding so many contradictory opinions. :(

Comment: This code would work??? u nutz?  `Weapon rs.getString("name") =...` doenst work. please understand java first. then understand the fundementals of hibernate then reflection.

Comment: I get an error(it won't work-I know that from learning Java)... "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".  I want to instantiate an instance of my weapon class, for every entry in the database, using the name field from the db for the instantiated name of the class.

Comment: @DarthVader I didn't read the `Weapon rs.getString("name")` code =\

Comment: @JayAvon replace the `Weapon rs.getString("name")` per `Weapon weapon` and the code will compile and run. Still, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you need variables with the name of the weapon or similar?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza: yes I would like to have an instance of the weapon class for each entry in my database without hard-coding them all.  They should also have some instance name that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ORM depends on your project size. Personally, and by looking at your understanding of Java, I would *not* recommend that you jump into hibernate and such for now. I would suggest that you play directly with SQL first so you have a better understanding of persistence.

As for the code you posted, here is what you could do :

```
//Setup the weapon classes
logger.info("Initializing the weapon classes.");
stat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *" + 
                            " FROM " + DB_NAME + ".weapons");

HashMap<String, Weapon> weapons = new HashMap<String, Weapon>();

rs = stat.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    Weapon weapon = new Weapon()
        .setId(rs.getint("weapon_id"))
        .setName(rs.getString("name"))
        .setDescription(rs.getString("description"))
        .setFilename(rs.getString("filename"))
        .setRarity(rs.getint("rarity"))
        .setSellPrice(rs.getint("sell_price"))
        .setQuantityMax(rs.getint("quantity_max"))
        .setSlot(rs.getint("slot"))
        .setLvlRequirement(rs.getint("level_requirement"))
        .setStrRequirement(rs.getint("strength_requirement"))
        .setDexRequirement(rs.getint("dexterity_requirement"))
        .setIntRequirement(rs.getint("intelligence_requirement"))
        .setEnchantedInc(rs.getint("enchanted_increase"))
        .setEnchantedCost(rs.getint("enchanted_cost"))
        .setHitMin(rs.getint("hit_min"))
        .setHitMax(rs.getint("hit_max"))
        .setSpeed(rs.getint("speed"))
        .setElementalType(rs.getint("elemental_type"))
        .setElementalHitMin(rs.getint("elemental_hit_min"))
        .setElementalHitMax(rs.getint("elemental_hit_max"));

    weapons.put(rs.getString("name"), weapon);
}
```

Avoid having a constructor (or even a method!) with so many arguments. Unless you are exporting your class to a third party or exposing it to some user plugins and don't want anyone to change the internal values, don't worry about setters! Then each `set*` methods return `this` so they can be chained. For example :

```
public Weapon setHitMax(int max) {
    this.hitMax = max;
    return this;
}
```

And you can, then access your weapons using the `Map`. Like, for example :

```
weapons.get("sword").getHitMax();
```

Comment: I want to thank both you and Sujay for the answers.  I wish I could accept both, but have chosen yours so the next fellow who Google's this post sees the complete code up top.  Any important differences between choosing HashMap and Map I should be aware of?

Comment: @JayAvon: Map is an interface, HashMap is an implementation of this interface

Comment: Map is an interface, whereas HashMap is a concrete class

Comment: You should read [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Comment: Thank you and thank you... is now a bad time to mention I have been coding this MMORPG for the past year :P.  I want to become a better coder so I'm not starting small.

Comment: keep at it! it's by coding and asking questions that one improves

Comment: that's the idea.  Thanks so much guys, much appreciated.  Shameless plug in case you are intrigued... www.kisnardonline.com

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store your instance for weapons that you fetch from your database. The key would be the name and the value would be an instance of your Weapons class.

Something like:

```
while(rs.next()){
    Weapon weapon = new Weapon(rs.getint("weapon_id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getString("description"), rs.getString("filename"), rs.getint("rarity"), rs.getint("sell_price"), rs.getint("quantity_max"), rs.getint("slot"), rs.getint("level_requirement"), rs.getint("strength_requirement"), rs.getint("dexterity_requirement"), rs.getint("intelligence_requirement"), rs.getint("enchanted_increase"), rs.getint("enchanted_cost"), rs.getint("hit_min"), rs.getint("hit_max"), rs.getint("speed"), rs.getint("elemental_type"), rs.getint("elemental_hit_min"), rs.getint("elemental_hit_max"));
    //Assuming you have an instance of Map<String, Weapon>
    map.add(rs.getString("name"), weapon);
}
```

Comment: awesome, I love it.  Thanks a bunch.  Makes perfect sense and should work well.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "dynamic class creation"? There's two things I can understand from your code:

a) you're a reaallly bad Java programmer :)
    or

b) you're trying to have your **variable** named differently for each row in the database, (which doesn't make any sense)

Comment: say I have 3 weapons in the db(sword/axe/dagger); I want three instances of the weapon class in my java code. one instance named sword, one named axe, and the last dagger.

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't know the big picture, but this seems like a bad idea. You should build a HashMap and, for each row, do a yourMap.put(yourWeaponName, weaponObject). Then, when you need the axe, all you do is yourMap.get("axe") and there's your axe...